# How to append a css class if user has specific role?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, thymeleaf

How to append a class to an element with `th:classappend` only if the user has a specific role?

Something like this:

```html
<div th:classappend="${hasRole('EDITOR')?'glow':''}"></div>
```

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Security and Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on [Thymeleaf "extras" Spring Security GitHub page](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity):

```html
<div th:classappend="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''EDITOR'')')?'glow':''}"></div>
```

Comment: This should be to correct answer nowadays, since `#request` is no longer accessible in current Thymeleaf versions.

Answer (score 1):

**Version note:** Below does not work in Thymeleaf 3.1+ due to new security restrictions.

You can use the *request* variable, which points to the current [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html):

```xml
<div th:classappend="${#request.isUserInRole('EDITOR')?'glow':''}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use classes for your roles.

`Roles.java`

```java
public enum Role {

    MEMBER("MEMBER"),
    ADMIN("ADMIN");

    public final String name;

    Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`template.html`

```html
<div class="btn" th:classappend="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''' + (T(com.mycompany.Role).MEMBER) + ''')')} ? 'btn-primary' : 'disabled'"></div>
```